# Is there a shortcut to setting a variable to the greater of 2 values?

Tags: ruby, shortcut

Say I'm looking for the greater of 2 sets of *n* numbers (for the sake of example) and I had this algorithm:

```
def maxofarrays set1 set2
    greater_array = []
    set1.each_index do |index|
        if set1[index] > set2[index] then greater_array << set1[index]
        else greater_array << set2[index]
    end
    greater_array
end
```

Is there a shortcut to the two innermost lines of code? Or do I have to type it out?

Comment: I'd recommend you to search "ruby functional programming" in google.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = [347, 163, 436, 234, 113]
b = [213, 566, 124, 212, 963]
c = a.zip(b).map(&:max)
#=> [347, 566, 436, 234, 963]
```

Comment: [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260) interleaves the values from the receiver and argument(s), while [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core/) returns the max of all values in the Enumerable.